# Identifying key field in SAP table while using JCo3

Tags: abap, jco, bapi, sap-erp

I am using JCo3. While working with BAPI, i get tables that are part of it. While reading metadata of these tables, i will be interested to know which field is the primary key field for the table.

This is important for me while writing persistence related code in java.

Edited:

In fact, I am interested in all BAPIs. For example: BAPI_PO_CREATE1, BAPI_GOODSMVT_CANCEL, etc

Idea is to make this part of the base classes so that the key is identified automatically. I also would like to understand the exceptions, if any.

Comment: Could you please add the names of the BAPIs in question? This will make it easier to answer the question...

Comment: @vwegert, i have edited the question to indicate the BAPI names.

Comment: Did you get an answer for this?

Comment: Yes. We can use the function module "DDIF_FIELDINFO_GET". Note that this is not a BAPI. Are you building something interesting? Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

I found the function module "DDIF_FIELDINFO_GET" useful to get field level metadata. This metadata has information to indicate if it is a Key field.

Good Luck!!